# ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (23) Error in Http Request: Timeout was reached

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-factory

I am using my ADF copy pipeline to extract data from SalesForce. Till yesterday everything is fine and running and now we are getting Timeout error as per the below message.

Error codeUserErrorFailedToConnectOdbcSource

Failure typeUser configuration issue

DetailsFailure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToConnectOdbcSource,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (23) Error in Http Request: Timeout was reached ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (23) Error in Http Request: Timeout was reached,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (23) Error in Http Request: Timeout was reached ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (23) Error in Http Request: Timeout was reached,Source=,'

Is there any idea what's wrong going on this..?

Azure Data Factory

I tried some of them tables manuall by copy and its same error.

Comment: And just to update.. For testing I create the one copy activity and then I tired to load one object from Salesforce and its runs sucessfuully and then I tired second time and its give me same above timeout error.. so I dont know basically what's going on.. Is there anything on SalesForce disturbing us or any network issue...?

Comment: is this [Answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1188011/(microsoft)(salesforce)-(23)-error-in-http-request) helped you?

Comment: We are still in diagnose face and soon I will update here.